# Matlab: using file name as a variable

Tags: matlab

So I have a code_answer script and a grading script. I'm trying to create a (3rd) main script that will call the code_answer script, save the name of that script to a variable, then use that variable in the fopen() of the grading script. I want it to work so that all I have to do is change the file name of the first script called in the main script and it will then use this new filename with the fopen for the second script called from main. something like this:

```
%MAIN SCRIPT:

%answer script   
codeanswerscript_1

var = sprintf('%?', above file name)

%grading script
grading_script  %which then uses var for an fopen() inside this script
```

I know I can't assign a filename to a variable like this, but I'm trying to find a workaround. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Assign the filename manually to `var` and use `run` to execute the script or use `mfilename` inside the first script.
Option 1:

```
var = 'code_answer';
run(var);
grading_script;
```

Option 2:
In `code_answer` use the following line -

```
var = mfilename;
```

Note that the second option won't work if `code_answer` is a function.